# Android unreported exception IOException error

Tags: java, android, ioexception

I am new to android apps development. Recently,Im writing an application which able to show public ip based on [Ipify](https://bitbucket.org/stevenjeffries/java-ipify). So far, i already:

- Download the required jar file and put inside libs folder
- I also compile file within gradle
- Then i import required class it to my class

How to use Ipify, according to its website:

```
import org.ipify.Ipify;

public class HelloIP {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(Ipify.getPublicIp());
    }
}
```

I write the following method to be invoked from another class:

```
public static String getPublicIp() throws IOException{
    String ip = Ipify.getPublicIp();
    return ip;
}
```

Another Class

```
//Get wifi
getWifiName wifiInfo = new getWifiName();
String myIP = wifiInfo.getPublicIp();
```

However, i keep getting:

> Error:(52, 43) error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught
>   or declared to be thrown

I tried to modify the code and use the following try and catch, but still got the same error.

```
public static String getPublicIp() throws IOException{
    String myip = Ipify.getPublicIp();
    try{
        return myip;
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("General I/O exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Im not too good in catch and throw exception, and already spent the whole day for this.I dont have idea anymore to fix this error..T.T

Comment: *and use the following try and catch* ... try aroud plain `return` statment ... fascinating

Comment: What was the reason for unaccept?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getPublicIp() {
    try{
        return Ipify.getPublicIp();
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("General I/O exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

In case it didn't help, `clean project` in your IDE. You may have some data cached and it might be a reason.

Your problem is in **another class**! As you have declared the method `getPublicIp()` to throw `IOException` that class is afraid of receiving the `Exception` and therefor requests catching it.

In Java you have two types of Exceptions. Checked and unchecked. Checked Exceptions must be caught.

In Java Exceptions are used for marking unexpected situations. For example parsing non-numeric `String` to a number (`NumberFormatException`) or calling a method on a `null` reference (`NullPointerException`). You can catch them in many ways.

Unchecked `Exception`s are those which extend `RunTimeException`. They are used for marking unexpected states usually caused by user's input. They shouldn't cause harm and should be worked out with business logic. You don't have to catch them, but sometimes you should.

On the other hand there are Checked `Exception`s which mark dangerous situations. For example the application being unable to open a file. As those situations are found dangerous, you must catch them.

```
try{
    //some code
} catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
    e.printStackTrace()     //very important - handles the Exception but prints the information!
} catch (NullPointerException e2) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or using the fact, that they all extend `Exception`:

```
try {
    //somecode
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace;
};
```

or since Java 7:

```
try {
    //somecode
} catch (NullPointerException | NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding to uncheck and checked exception, thats a new information for me. I managed to make the code running, however im using another library which is JSOUP.